# Where is the Identity (Token) Login httppost action method in Web API project?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-identity

In MVC project (.NET Framework), the Scaffolding Identity Login action method is below:

```
// POST: /Account/Login
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return View(model);
    }

    // This doesn't count login failures towards account lockout
    // To enable password failures to trigger account lockout, change to shouldLockout: true
    var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Email, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: false);
    switch (result)
    {
        case SignInStatus.Success:
            return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
        case SignInStatus.LockedOut:
            return View("Lockout");
        case SignInStatus.RequiresVerification:
            return RedirectToAction("SendCode", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl, RememberMe = model.RememberMe });
        case SignInStatus.Failure:
        default:
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid login attempt.");
            return View(model);
    }
}
```

But I seem could not find the Scaffolding Identity Login action method in **Web API** project (.NET Framework). I search for `SignInManager` or `PasswordSignInAsync` as keyword but could not find any. I could find `AddExternalLogin` but this method take `AddExternalLoginBindingModel` as parameter which is not username, email and password.

```
public class AddExternalLoginBindingModel
{
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "External access token")]
    public string ExternalAccessToken { get; set; }
}
```

After some read up, I notice that if the client is using Javascript to call the Web API login method, it is going to something like `https://localhost:44358/api/Token` but I can't this `Token` method in Web Api Scaffolding Identity controller.

Comment: You would need to generate your `Token`. By default, the project won't generate any token mechanism as such. An example can be found here: https://www.dotnetcurry.com/aspnet/1223/secure-aspnet-web-api-using-tokens-owin-angularjs

Comment: Thanks. Do you have any example for asp.net mvc (.net framework) as client instead of angular?

Comment: This link would be helpful: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1183150/Securing-ASP-NET-Web-API-using-Custom-Token-Based